# How to delete application from Flurry analytics

Tags: flurry

I have dev and production applications. We decided to remove dev because it doesn't influence to live statistics at all.

Unfortunately I didn't find way how to delete app in Flurry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figure out that I don't have privileges for app deletion. That's why I don't see page with button to delete app.

Comment: Looks like its possible now. Click on your app, then click on Manage from the left menu, then click on Advanced. Now you can see the option to Delete Application.